# How to cache a value in an ngFor directive in Angular2?

Tags: angular, caching, ngfor

My component has the activity property which has the totalLoad() method that computes extensive numbers, but could also return null if parameters are wrong ( otherwise return a structure containing 'load').
In an ngFor, I'd like to access to load properties if and only if the method doesn't return null.
How would you do that?

```
<td *ngFor="let d of monthDays">
    {{activity.totalLoad(member.code, d.day).load}} h
</td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed from your question that you are trying to avoid template errors when trying to access some property, right?

If I'm right, you can do it using the [**`Safe Navigation Operator`**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator):

```
<td *ngFor="let d of monthDays">
    {{activity.totalLoad(member.code, d.day)?.load}} h
</td>
```

Check a simple demo using the operator:

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiyY8nXV3LMRfM3BIPgh?p=info)</kbd>

Comment: in the case I have a null, how would you get rid of the unit 'h'?

Comment: I would do the following: `{{activity.totalLoad(member.code, d.day)?.load}} <ng-container *ngIf="activity.totalLoad(member.code, d.day)">h</ng-container>`

Comment: Thanks. By exploiting your answer and Günter's answer, I ended up with a more compact solution as follows: {{load ? load+" h" : "" }}. Is that sounds good to you? (load is the map() of totalLoad)

Answer (score 1):

Binding to a method this way in the view is usually a bad idea. 
Every time Angular runs change detection, this method is executed.

A better approach is to store the calculated values in an array and use `ngFor` on this array.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.totalLoads = this.monthDays
  .map(md => this.activity.totalLoad(this.member.code, md.day).load);
}
```

```ts
<td *ngFor="let td of totalLoads">
    {{td}} h
</td>
```

Comment: Actually, the right answer is the union of your answer and developer033's. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally did this (it's the union of the two answers above):

In the component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.totalLoads = this.monthDays
  .map(md => this.activity.totalLoad(this.member.code, md.day).load);
}
```

In the component.html:

```
<td *ngFor="let td of totalLoads">
    {{td ? td+" h":""}}
</td>
```

Comment: Well, I could suggest you to do everything on your component file. Changing map to: `.map(md => {
  const x: any = this.activity.totalLoad(this.member.code, md.day);
  if (x !== undefined && x !== null) {
    return x.load + ' h';
  } else {
    return '';
  }
});`